# Need to simplify formula $ \pi \sim \frac{8}{n^2} \cdot \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \sqrt{i \cdot (n - i)} $

Tags: calculus, integration, pi, elementary-functions

This formula can be simplified?

$$ \pi \sim \frac{8}{n^2} \cdot \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \sqrt{i \cdot (n - i)} $$

I am trying to find an alternative formula for circle area.
I stacked to analyze this formula for a while without any progress.

This is not my home work.
I am asking here, because I know all the professional mathematician are here and maybe exist such theorem that I do not know yet and can help to move further with my research.

Thank You.

I tested convergence numerically with:

```
import math

p = 6
n = 10 ** p

sum_h = 0
for i in range(n+1):
    h = (i * (n - i)) ** (1/2)
    sum_h = sum_h + h

pi0 = 8 * sum_h / n / n

print(" ", math.pi)
print("~", pi0)
```

```
  3.141592653589793
~ 3.141592650263593
```

Here is what I know.

[image]

Preview integral example.

[image]

We are so close!

[image]

Comment: The sum probably can't be simplified.

Comment: There is highly unlikely that there is a closed form. However, you can write down an asymptotic expansion $$
S_n \sim \frac{\pi }{8}n^2 +2\zeta \left( -\tfrac{1}{2}\right)n^{1/2}-\zeta \left(-\tfrac{3}{2} \right)n^{ - 1/2}  - \frac{1}{4}\zeta \left( { - \tfrac{5}{2}} \right)n^{ - 3/2}  - \frac{1}{8}\zeta \left(-\tfrac{7}{2}\right)n^{-5/2}+\ldots 
$$ for large $n$ in terms of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta$. You can prove this via the polylogarithm generating function ${\rm Li}_{-1/2}^2 (z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty S_n z^n$ and techniques used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4626126).

Comment: The question has been changed but an asymptotic answer still follows from my comment.

Comment: @Gary, You correctly answered, that the result is $ \frac{\pi}{8} \cdot n^2 $, but I am looking to simplify this radicals with something simple.

Comment: Sometimes there is no simpler solution.

Comment: Have you used the fact that you sum is approximately $8\int_0^1\sqrt{x(1-x)}\mathrm{d}x$ when $n$ is large? You can find this integral using elementary methods, and you'll get that it equals $\pi$.

Comment: @Gary, Yes, but I hope to find something.

Comment: @MatthewH., Yes, we can replace almost any sum with integral. You mention a very good point. But if I am not wrong, integral cannot calculate pi value, there are used some series of arcsin or different series of inverse trigonometric functions. True or I must know something new?

Comment: @MatthewH. The OP seems to look for a simpler form of the sum and not a simpler way to show the asymptotics.

Comment: @Vitalie That integral is $B(3/2,3/2)=\pi/8$ in terms of the beta function.

Comment: @Gary, You are very smart, but I need something simple, as simple that any child can play with.

Comment: @Vitalie You have to understand that mathematics is not always simple. You can try to compute the integral by substituting $x=\sin^2 t$, $0<t<\pi/2$.

Comment: @Gary, Yes, but I need something simple to break this vicious circle. Something that any child will be able to play with and be trivial. I am dreaming to a method that can express circle area as integer value. :)

Comment: @Vitalie The area of the unit circle is $\pi$ which is not an integer. See some formulas [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html).

Comment: The sum $\frac{1}{{n^2 }}\sum\limits_{i = 0}^n {\sqrt {i(n - i)} }  = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i = 0}^n {\sqrt {\frac{i}{n}\left( {1 - \frac{i}{n}} \right)} } $ is a Riemann sum for the integral $\int_0^1\sqrt{x(1-x)}\mathrm{d}x$, whose value is $\pi/8$. This is what you are observing numerically. Read about the [Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral). There is no way forward in mathematics if you are not willing to learn and understand new, perhaps more difficult concepts.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Gary gave in comments the most perfect asymptotic formula you could expect.

Working the asymptotics of a lower bound, consider
$$F(n)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \sqrt{i\,(n - i)}\qquad\text{and}\qquad 
G(n)=\int_0^{n-1} \sqrt{i\,(n - i)}\,di$$ $$G(n)=\frac{1}{4} \left(n^2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{n-1}\right)+(n-2)
   \sqrt{n-1}\right)$$ For all $n$  the sum is larger than the integral. Recall that
$$\int_0^{n} \sqrt{i\,(n - i)}\,di=\frac{\pi  }{8}n^2$$

Now, using series expansion, the lower bound is
$$G(n)=\frac{\pi  }{8}n^2-\frac{2 \sqrt{n}}{3}\left( 1-\frac{3}{10 n}-\frac{3}{56 n^2}-\frac{1}{48 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$ which makes
$$\frac 8{n^2}F(n)> \pi-\frac{16}{3 n^{3/2}}\left( 1-\frac{3}{10 n}-\frac{3}{56 n^2}-\frac{1}{48 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$

For $n=100$, the lhs is $3.13827$ while the rhs is $3.13628$

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

Provided formula $$ \pi \sim \frac{8}{n^2} \cdot \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \sqrt{i \cdot (n-i)} $$
is similar with
$$  \pi \sim \frac{4}{n^2} \cdot \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \sqrt{n^2 - i^2} = \frac{4}{n^2} \cdot \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \sqrt{(n+i) \cdot (n-i)} $$

Expressing equivalently with integral

$$ \int_{0}^{n} \sqrt{n-x} \sqrt{n+x} dx = \frac{\pi n^2}{4} $$

Comment: You can simplify the integral via the change of variables $x=n\cdot t$.

Answer (score 0):

Using binomial expansion:

$$\int\limits_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2} dx = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!} \int\limits_{0}^{1} x^{2k}dx$$
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2} dx = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!} \frac{1}{2k+1} \to  \frac{\pi}{4}$$